# preferredFocusedView for tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos

I am looking at Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFocusEnvironment_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UIFocusEnvironment/preferredFocusedView) and not able to implement it in my swift project. I want to set a UIButton as the first focused in View when the app starts but cant figure out how.

I am primarily looking to do something like this:
`override func preferredFocusedView` .... but obviously that is not it

Answer (score 2):

It's a property, not a function, so you need to do this in Swift:

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    get {
        return viewYouWantToFocus
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your UIViewController override `get{}` for `preferredFocusedView` to return your UIButton. Then make sure to call `setNeedsFocusUpdate()`. That should do it. (You can also implement `set{}` so that you can easily change which object receives focus, but again, remember to call `setNeedsFocusUpdate()` after changing it).